# how to save api data in fragment back stack from fragment two to fragment one on back button clicked

Tags: android, fragment, fragment-backstack

i have two fragments,in first fragment i have list of invoice details with check box in list view .
i need to store the list items while back from the second fragment

1st fragment:

```
MakePayment debtorsAging = MakePayment.newInstance();
debtorsAging.setArguments(bundle);

FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, debtorsAging,MakePayment.TAG);

fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(PaymentCollection.class.getName());
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

2nd fragment:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft=fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.remove(new MakePayment());
ft.commit();
fragmentManager.popBackStackImmediate();
```

need to restore list of invoices with checked items on go back from **makePayment** fragment to **paymentCollection** fragment

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Passing data back to previous fragment from current fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42711554/passing-data-back-to-previous-fragment-from-current-fragment)

Answer (score 0):

If you back to previous activity by onBackPressed (not by transaction) i think you cant pass anythig between fragments by bundle or something. One of resolution I suggest to save id's or something to SharedPreferences before back to previous activity and restore them in first fragment

Comment: thanks, i saved the selected position in spinner while backstack im using setselction (position) now its perfect.